# Create second Redirect in PHP file (Firefox)

Tags: php, redirect

Here is what I am trying to do. 
I am creating a form, and after the submit and return of an ID, it redirects them to a certain confirmation page.
Here is the end of my submit page code (I know it gets all the variables I need already, so irrelevant I think right now):

```
if (!$sessionid)
{
    echo "There was an error, please try again.";   
}
else
{
    //echo "Thank you for registering. You will receive a confirmation shortly. If you don't please contact us.";
    include ('confirmation.php');
    $url = 'http://www.gmtoptions.com/deposit.aspx?c=c&s=' . $sessionid;
    echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="5; URL='.$url.'">'; 
}
```

In the confirmation.php file, is this:

```
$url = 'http://www.gmtoptions.com/registration-confirmation.aspx';
    echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">';
```

So confirmation.php is the firs redirect. It redirects to this confirmation page, then it's supposed to redirect to the deposit page. It works like a charm in Chrome, but IE and Firefox don't work. IE and Firefox stop at the first redirect. These are outside pages, so I can't do any coding or scripting on them. How do I get it to redirect to the second page in the other browsers?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I don't think this is doing what you think it is doing. A single page can have one and only one meta refresh redirect. Once that redirect happens the browser is no longer on your page to respond to further redirect requests.  If you have found that some browsers allow you to do this, it must surely be just a bug in the browser that allows this.  I would not depend on this functionality at all.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `<?php header('refresh:0; url='.$url); ?>` in the second page